# Apache RewriteRule to handle multiple domains

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, httpd.conf

I am trying to set redirection in Apache (httpd.conf), the requirement is simple, whenever there is an access to my domain those access should be redirected to different URL. I wrote this code when the server is setup, and handled one domain only. That code worked when there is only one domain and redirected to destination properly.

I have added one more domain and trying to do the same redirection. Unfortunately the redirection seems to be not working after adding the second domain redirection code.

**Requirement:**

Redirect all the files under 'chk' and 'enq' directories to it's mobile domain

**Initial rewrite rule**

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/chk/q/(.*) https://st-iex.o-p.com/lnk000/=https://st-ex.o-p.com/chk/q/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/enq/q/(.*) https://st-iex.o-p.com/lnk000/=https://st-ex.o-p.com/enq/q/$1 [L]
RewriteLog "/var/log/httpd/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

The above code worked when I have the domain st-iex.o-p.com only.

I have updated the code handle second domain redirection

**Version 2**

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^st-iex\.o-p\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/chk/q/(.*) https://st-iex.o-p.com/lnk000/=https://st-ex.o-p.com/chk/q/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/enq/q/(.*) https://st-iex.o-p.com/lnk000/=https://st-ex.o-p.com/enq/q/$1 [L]
RewriteLog "/var/log/httpd/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^st-iex-t\.o-p\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/chk/q/(.*) https://st-iex-t.o-p.com/lnk000/=https://st-ex.o-p.com/chk/q/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/enq/q/(.*) https://st-iex-t.o-p.com/lnk000/=https://st-ex.o-p.com/enq/q/$1 [L]
RewriteLog "/var/log/httpd/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

After code update, it doesn't work and there is no redirection made.
Could anyone can help me to fix this redirection issue?

Comment: What gets logged in the `rewrite.log` file?

Comment: @hjpotter92 this is what i can see in the rewrite.log file

127.0.0.1 - - [26/Nov/2015:15:29:23 +0900] [127.0.0.1/sid#2ac715d95380][rid#2ac71b0f6900/initial] (3) applying pattern '^/chk/q/(.*)' to uri '/refresh/'

127.0.0.1 - - [26/Nov/2015:15:29:23 +0900] [127.0.0.1/sid#2ac715d95380][rid#2ac71b0f6900/initial] (3) applying pattern '^/enq/q/(.*)' to uri '/refresh/'

127.0.0.1 - - [26/Nov/2015:15:29:23 +0900] [127.0.0.1/sid#2ac715d95380][rid#2ac71b0f6900/initial] (1) pass through /refresh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the RewriteRule as below and then the issue is fixed now.
Thank you.

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} st-iex\.o-p\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/chk/q/(.*) https://st-iex.o-p.com/lnk000/=https://st-ex.o-p.com/chk/q/$1 [L, R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} st-iex\.o-p\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/enq/q/(.*) https://st-iex.o-p.com/lnk000/=https://st-ex.o-p.com/enq/q/$1 [L, R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} st-iex-t\.o-p\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/chk/q/(.*) https://st-iex-t.o-p.com/lnk000/=https://st-ex.o-p.com/chk/q/$1 [L, R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} st-iex-t\.o-p\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/enq/q/(.*) https://st-iex-t.o-p.com/lnk000/=https://st-ex.o-p.com/enq/q/$1 [L, R=301]
RewriteLog "/var/log/httpd/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3
```